# Multiple select to popup a new window on clicking options one by one

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, popupwindow, multipleselection

I have a requirement to popup a url on clicking on multiple select options one by one. It means when i click on one option it should pop up a new window where user can submit some data and return to previous html window. Now again the user can select one options(Ctrl+click) and it should open a new pop up window. But the Pop up url is containing values of option.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="FldSel" name="FldSel" size=15 onchange="callInstrumentField();"  >                                                                  
    <option isred= "A" value="1">1</option>
    <option isred= "A" value="2">2</option>
    <option isred= "A" value="3">3</option>                                                                                             
    <option isred= "A" value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

// Javascript function is:

```
 function callInstrumentField()
 {

       var url;
       var w;
       var InstAct;
       var InstName = document.ATTForm.instname.value.replace(/\s/gi,"");
       var sel = document.getElementById('FldSel');
       var selected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
       var FldSelVel = sel.value;
       var FldType = selected.getAttribute("isred");
       var x2 = document.ATTForm.InstrAction.value;

       if(InstName=="")
             {
             alert("Please Enter Instrument Name");
             document.getElementById("instname").focus();
             return false;
        }
        else{
            if(x2=="UPDATE")
                {
                InstAct= 'SELECT';
            }
            else
                {
                InstAct=x2;
            }
       //var x2="SELECT";
            if (FldType == "Dropdown")
                {
                url = '?func=lsdms.ViewInstrumentFldSel&InstrAction='+InstAct+'&InstruMntNo='+FldSelVel;
                w = window.open(url,"","height=340,width=680,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes");

                if ( w.focus )
                    {
                    w.focus();
                }

            }
        } 
}
```

But its not working in the desired way. Every time its passing previously selected option values inside script.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code around getting the correctly selected option and i find nothing wrong with it.

If you debug via chrome tools and add a breakpoint on the

```
var FldSelVel = sel.value;
```

line you should be able to interrogate the values.

**Update**

---

Multi select can be detected by iterating over the options and testing its selected value

```
for (x=0;x< sel.options.length;x++)
  {
    if(sel.options[x].selected)
      {
        alert(sel.options[x].value);             
      }
  }
```

If you need to trigger an event on click you can use jQuery

```
$('#FldSel').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  alert(value);
});
```

Instead of the alert you can now put the call to display the popup.

Comment: The problem is with the multiple select option.when i select the multiple values its always pass the the first selected value.